# 75 of my reputation has suddenly disappeared by a user removal, may I ask some details?

Tags: discussion

I know that voting info is a highly secret data on the SE rules, and even the mods don't have access to it.

It was a self-destruction, or some problematic activity was detected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am sorry, no - these sort of details are not provided.

Read [Why did I just lose some reputation without any explanation in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133299/154443) for a little more information.